# XAMPP installation unknown error

Tags: php, xampp

When installed the **XAMPP**, I came across this error:

```
Unknown error while running explorer.
```

Please click this picture for more details:

[image]

Can someone help me to figure out this error?

Comment: try reinstalling it,i once happened with me also i had to install the whole window again

Comment: I tried to reinstall for several times, but it turned out with the same error. I do not know why. So strange.